# integer overflow in expression of type 'int' results

Tags: c++, esp32, sleep, integer

i need to wake up my ESP every 60 min to read some data and post it to server, all process working fine when i use numbers of minute below 60 (converted in microsecond x 1000000) but when i use 60 min above i get the following message:

> src/main.cpp:137:49: warning: integer overflow in expression of type 'int' results in '-694967296' [-Woverflow]
> esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP * uS_TO_S_FACTOR);// set up next wake up after 30 sec

How can i make my ESP wake up every 60 min or above?

simplify code:

```
// for awake and sleep
#define uS_TO_S_FACTOR 1000000  
#define TIME_TO_SLEEP  60 // minute


void setup(){
esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP * 60 * uS_TO_S_FACTOR);// error if time to sleep more than 60 min  
}
```

Comment: More or less the same question [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/91670/70020). On the ESP32 the `long ` and `int` types have the same range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that line to:

```
esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup((uint64_t) TIME_TO_SLEEP * 60 * uS_TO_S_FACTOR);
```

That forces the compiler to do 64-bit arithmetic on the constant rather than defaulting to "int" arithmetic.